# How to filter specific values in a .xml file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm little new to the python programming and looking for some help to filter out some values from a .xml file and store them in  DB. Below is the sample .xml file.

```
<real:test="56348364" Id="test_1">

         <rex:test>

         <real:cut build_id="kusfjfkjhlkg-8348753984-kdjf-84kf94-ftteh"/>

</real:test>
```

According to the above .xml, I need to filter the build_id values as follows,

```
build_id="kusfjfkjhlkg-8348753984-kdjf-84kf94-ftteh"
```

how I can get it filtered ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid XML. It's a good thing that [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) can handle such broken syntax.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<real:test="56348364" Id="test_1">

         <rex:test>

         <real:cut build_id="kusfjfkjhlkg-8348753984-kdjf-84kf94-ftteh"/>

</real:test>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

# find by tag name
for e in soup.find_all('real:cut'):
    print(e['build_id'])

# find any element with a build_id attribute
for e in soup.find_all('real:cut', {'build_id': True}):
    print(e.name, e['build_id'])
```